# How to edit values of an object inside an array inside a class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, javascript-objects

If I have a class with a constructor and in the constructor an array with objects and I want an object method to edit the values of the objects, it gets kind of messy.

This is what I'm kind of aiming for:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.o = [
      {
        name: "John",
        changeName: () => {
          this.name = "Mike";
        },
      },
    ];
  }
}

SomeClass.o[0].changeName();
```

But that doesn't work because the `this` refers to the class and not the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create an instance with `new` if you want the constructor to run.

Don't use arrow functions when you want `this` to refer to the object you called the method on.

So correct like this:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.o = [
      {
        name: "John",
        changeName() { // not an arrow function
          this.name = "Mike";
        },
      },
    ];
  }
}

let obj = new SomeClass(); // use `new`

obj.o[0].changeName();

console.log(obj.o[0].name);
```